# How can i pass 'nil' as a value of parameter through hidden_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

IN my application Controller

```
class FeedEntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = FeedEntry.search(params[:search])
    @feed_entries = @search.page(params[:page])
    @app_keys = AppKey.all
  end
end
```

And in my Views/feed_entries/index.html.erb

```
<li>
    <%= form_for @search do |f|%>
    <%= f.hidden_field :last_clicked_on, value: 'nil' %>
    <%= f.submit "History" %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

I am using the `gem 'meta_search'` for search the database.

feed_entries table contains last_clicked_on:datetime attribute, it is nil by default. I just want to pass 'nil' as a value of last_clicked_on attribute. So that, controller will search `last_clicked_on = nil`  alone.

Please someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to search for `last_clicked_on` being nil, you should probably add a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to your model.

If you'd rather not do that, you can skip the hidden field, and just add to the params hash:

```
params[:search][:last_clicked_on] = nil
```

prior to performing your search